# Sum through columns depending on date

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Im trying to add actuals depending on the current month. Let's say for example I'm in March. The formula would add data from January till February. I have the MONTH(TODAY()) formula to get the current month, and played around with INDEX, but can't figure out how to get a working formula without doing it manually.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

add actuals depending on the current month

Comment: Try `=IF(MONTH(TODAY())=1,0,SUM(TAKE(A2:L2,MONTH(TODAY())-1)))` (M365) or `=IF(MONTH(TODAY())=1,0,SUM(A2:INDEX(A2:L2,MONTH(TODAY())-1)))` (legacy).

Answer (score 1):

Try using `TAKE()` & `SUM()`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B6</kbd>

```
=SUM(TAKE(B4:M4,,MONTH(A1)))
```

---

**Note:** Cell <kbd>A1</kbd> `=TODAY()`

---

Or, Using `CHOOSECOLS()` & `SEQUENCE()`

[image]

---

```
=SUM(CHOOSECOLS(B4:M4,SEQUENCE(,A1)))
```

---

**Note:** Cell <kbd>A1</kbd> `=MONTH(TODAY())`

---

If `MONTH()` function is used in cell `A1` then

```
=SUM(TAKE(B4:M4,,A1))
```

---

If not using `MS365` then :

[image]

---

```
=SUM(INDEX(B4:M4,,1):INDEX(B4:M4,,A1))
```

---

Or,

```
=SUM(B4:INDEX(B4:M4,,A1))
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution, see screen step by step.

A full all-in-one formula will be:

```
=SUM(
    C$12:
        INDEX($C$12:$H$12,1,
            MATCH(B1,
                MAP($C$11:$H$11,
                    LAMBDA(a,
                        MONTH(
                            DATEVALUE(a&1)
))))))
```

where

- `B1` is number of months to sum from January
- `$C$11:$H$11` is range of month labels
- `$C$12:$H$12` is range of month value

`MAP()` converts your label range to dates by applying `LAMBDA(a,MONTH(DATEVALUE(a)&1)` to every `a` (that is, cell inside the range) to the range.

`MATCH()` finds by label value the position of this label value in the range.

`INDEX()` finds the actual address of the cell in this position.

[image: Solution step by step]

`MATCH` is optional if you are certain that your month label range will never change.

PS. Another option is just to change months as text strings to dates as serial numbers. If you want them to look pretty "month-name-only", format them as `"mmm"`. Then a simple `SUMPRODUCT()` will do the task.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to do the same, probably the most transparent.

`=FILTER(B4:B15,MONTH(A4:A15&1)<=B2)`

where:

- `B2` is the final month for selecting
- `A4:A15` is the range of month labels (Jan-Feb-...-Nov-Dec)
- `B4:B15` are values for each month

Step by step:

- `MONTH(A4:A15&1)` converts the range month labels from text to serial numbers `{Jan,Feb...} >> {1;2...}`
- `FILTER(range to filter, criteria for filter)` selects from month values `B4:B15` only those which correspond to month numbers in range generated by `MONTH()` that is less than or equal as month number in `B2`

With the range that `FILTER()` returns, you can do anything. `SUM(FILTER())` will return a sum, `MAX(FILTER())` will give you the maximum value, and so on.

[image: Using FILTER()]

I laid out your original data columnwise to make it more legible, you can do the same with rows or columns, as you like.

kudos to @z.. for pointing out further simplifications

Comment: wouldn't `MONTH(x&1)` without `DATEVALUE` work?

Comment: @z.. Yes, seems like DATEVALUE() step can also be dropped. Will make an edit.

Comment: I don't think you need the `MAP` either: `=FILTER(B4:B15,MONTH(A4:A15&1)<=B2)`. I am not very familiar with Excel so I may be wrong.

Comment: @z.. Interesting. It seems to work although should not. Anyway, since I added a wrong screenshot, will remove this step as well.